# Optional Relations in Entity Declaration

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

In order to maintain consistency across projects, we've created a library that will model the all entities in our database. However, when utilizing this library in various services we've run into a problem with relations. It's necessary for the core db library to model all the relations between entities, but some of the services do not need or care about those relations.

For instance, in the core db library A has a relation to B.

But one of the services may not need to know or care about B, so we're curious if there's a way to have that relation be optional using TypeORM.

Right now TypeORM throws the following error when an entity is loaded without its defined relation:

`Error: Entity metadata for A#B was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.`